# How to retrieve all messages from a conversation twilio

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am trying to retrieve a list of messages in a specific conversation using Twilio's api. I followed [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource#) api which allows me to retrieve messages matching filtered criteria. Below is my code:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

(async () => {
    try {
        const messages = await client.messages.list({
            from: fromNumber,
            to: toNumber,
            limit: 20,
        });

        console.log(messages);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

This is great, but it only lists the messages from `fromNumber`. I want to see messages from `toNumber` as well.

I believe [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource#list-all-conversation-messages) is the api that I should use:

```
const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.conversations.conversations('CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .messages
      .list({limit: 20})
      .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.sid)));
```

But I'm not sure how to obtain `CHXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`.

I realize I can use my code above and flip `toNumber` and `fromNumber` then stitch the messages together, but I'd like to get the entire conversation if possible.

Comment: How are you creating and adding participants to conversations?

Comment: @philnash I wish I knew the technical answer to that. I am using [Highlevel](https://www.gohighlevel.com/) to send texts.

Comment: Does Highlevel make the conversation SID available to you? If not, you can list and filter conversations using the API here, but I don't know if that helps: https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#read-multiple-conversation-resources